# E-bass tuned correctly but E string too loose

Tags: tuning, strings, bass-guitar, self-learning

I'm self-taught and new to bass, and I tuned my bass today (E-A-D-G, E being the lowest), but the E String seems a bit loose (It hits the neck sometimes, and I can bend it much further than the other strings). Is that normal? Have I done something wrong?

Comment: A clear photo of the fingerboard near the nut would be helpful to see if the strings are at least in the right positions and approximately the right gauges. A short audio or video of you playing the open strings would also be helpful. It could be as simple as a truss rod adjustment but more info is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably did nothing wrong, and normality is more a matter of taste.

If you feel that this string is too loose for you to be happy with maybe you should consider getting an higher gauge string. It will require more tension in order to achieve the same pitch.

Answer (score 0):

Has it been like that all the time you've had it? How did you tune it - with a tuner, by ear, against another instrument? What bass is it, and what gauge strings are on now? All points which are needed to give any helpful answers.

Going on the sparse information rendered, all I can suggest is you tuned the bottom string an octave too low. It wouldn't be the first time something like this has happened - the tuner says 'E', but that E could be an octave too high or an octave too low.